# Showing the road speed limit on Android

Tags: android

I am looking for an Android application that can display the speed limit of the road where I am located. I am mostly interested in the USA, particularly Boston and California. Gratis is better but not necessary.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24909445/3682599

Comment: and there is an app called [Speed Alert Live (Australia)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartlocationtech.speedalert&hl=en), but this app is available for _Australia_

Comment: Hmmm, by sampling your GPS, your Android can calculate how quickly you are travelling & alert you if you are speeding!! More that you asked for - I wonder if it exists (it could have saved me Eur 50 last week ;-).  See my related question http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16165/android-app-to-wanr-me-is-i-am-speeding

Comment: @Mawg I'm [pretty much always speeding since I live in the US](http://www.mit.edu/~jfc/NMA/limits.html) :) But before the take off I'm curious what speed I am supposed to abide by to make sure the potential fine stays reasonable.

Comment: Franck, I guess [my answer here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/16167/185) covers that as well – just see screenshots 2 & 3. As a side-effect it can even warn you when you're too fast ;)

Comment: @Izzy Thanks, nice! I hadn't seen that the speed limits were retrieved by the app (I thought one needed to enter it manually).

Comment: That's the case with most of them. The one in my answer is the only exception I've found so far (apart from the a little more expensive full-navigation-solutions which have it included).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CamSam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.camsam&hl=en):

- works in the United States
- indicates the legal speed limit
- free, but there exist a [pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.camsam.plus&hl=en) version as well.

[image: CamSam]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are the red/green bars at the top for?

Comment: @Undo I'm pretty curious too, I am taking the car tomorrow, I'll test the app and let you know!