# Android app to warn me I am speeding

Tags: android

[This question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16148/showing-the-road-speed-limit-on-android) asked for an Android app to display the current speed limit for the road being driven on.

I figure that if that can be done, then an app can regularly measure your GPS position & warn you if you are speeding.

Does anyone know of such an app?

Comment: A little broad without more specific requirements, so the answers will turn out to be a list: [Speedometer & HUDs](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_speedometer). Good examples would e.g. include [SpeedView](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codesector.speedview.free) and [Speed Watcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bondfamilynet.speedwatcherfree), both including a "speed warner".

Comment: @Izzy some good info there (+1), but they seem to be either just showing your speed, or warning if you exceed a limit which you manually set. I can't find one that is aware of the current speed limit for the road which you are driving on.

Comment: See? That's what I meant by "more specific requirements". Your question doesn't point out *that* being one ("matching against speed limits for the current location"). If you're driving at 300mph it's safe to say you're "speeding" regardless of your location (earth-bound, that is), so the two are perfectly matching the requirements you specified. Be welcome to [edit] your question [for improvements](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for probably is **[AlertOmatic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.glooton.AlertOmatic)**. As I have no car, I obviously haven't tested it personally; but it seems to match your requirements, and is well rated:

[image: AlertOmatic] [image: AlertOmatic] [image: AlertOmatic]
<sup>*AlertOmatic* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.glooton.AlertOmatic); click images for larger variants)</sup>

*AlertOmatic* features a world-wide database of speed limits which it matches against. So no need to setup a speed limit manually – though you can do so additionally if you like (see first screenshot). As the second and third screenshot show, the database also contains locations of speed traps (with cam or "manned").

Keep in mind that such an app cannot be guaranteed to always be 100% accurat – there are natural limitations:

- depending on weather conditions, your GPS might be less accurate
- depending on traffic conditions, different speed limits might apply (temporarily; think of accidents, traffic jams, and the like)
- depending on local conditions, the database might not always be up-to-date (think of construction sites etc.)

Screenshots and links are from the gratis, ad powered version. To get rid of the ads, [a paid version is available](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.glooton.AlertOmatic.pro) for US$ 4.

There are several other [Speed Limiter](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_speedometer#group_956) apps available, but most of them only work with limits you've set up manually, not considering "local conditions".